# LINQ query for ordering by a specific set list

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I am developing a little music application where I'm filling a drop-down list.

My issue is in the LINQ query that I run here:

```
var results = (from x in db.Keys
               where x.SongId == songId
               orderby x.ChordKey ascending
               select x.ChordKey).ToList();
```

My values for the ChordKey are always only going to be:

```
Ab, A, Bb, B, C, C#, Db, D, Eb, E, F, F#, Gb, G
```

I'd like them to be ordered as they are above, unfortunately `A` will appear before `Ab` etc. if ordered alphabetically.  Is there a way to have it ordered according to the specific standard above?

Comment: Whats the diff between C# and Db?   how about F# and Gb?

Comment: What if you create class `ChordKey` and implement `IComparer` for sorting them?

Comment: @CharlesBretana They are the same in sound but they can be read differently on chord sheets

Comment: @feeeper I'm not entirely sure how to do that?  Never used an IComparer before

Comment: is your ChordKey an enum?

Comment: @Developer No it's a string

Comment: nevermind, I was about to say what @Charles Bretana already did :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort :)

Comment: @BarryDoyle I add sample with `IComparer` as possible answer. Check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a custom sotring List that you can use its items order to order your specific List. This can be done by creating a list of the custom order and making use of the index of each item in that list. If there are `ChordKey` values that may not be in your list (doesn't seem the case, then you'll need further checking):

```
var sortingOrder = new List<string>()
{
    "Ab", "A", "Bb", "B", "C", "C#", "Db", "D", "Eb", "E", "F", "F#", "Gb", "G"
};

results = results.OrderBy(x => sortingOrder.IndexOf(x)).ToList();
```

This orders each item in your List by the index of the item in your sorting list.

Answer (score 3):

Use an enum for the keys with underlying integral values that sort the way you want.

```
public enum ChordKey 
{Ab=1, A=2, Bb=3, B=4, C=5, 
 Db=6, D=7, Eb=8, E=9, 
 F=10, Gb=11, G=12}
```

then

```
var results = (from x in db.Keys
           where x.SongId == songId
           orderby (int)x.ChordKey ascending
           select x.ChordKey).ToList();
```

Comment: Does this really work when querying against the database ?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is create class `ChordKey` and implement `IComparer` interface:

```
class ChordKey : IComparer {
    // the number of the Chord. For Ab is 1 (or 0), for "G" is 14 (or 13) for example
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    // name of the Chord. For Ab is "Ab"
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ChordKey(string name, int id) {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Compare(object a, object b) {
        var c1 = (ChordKey)a;
        var c2 = (ChordKey)a;

        return c1.Id - c2.Id;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in your LINQ queries:

```
var results = (from x in db.Keys
               where x.SongId == songId
               orderby x.ChordKey.Id ascending
               select x.ChordKey).ToList();
```